# Serial port adapter reads 5V data but not 3V data

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, serial, rs232, data

Each time I wanted to hook up a micro-controller UART to my computer via serial port, I make an adapter with the following schematic:

[image: circuit]

For the capacitor, I use 47nF and for the diode, I use 1N4001. VCC is 5VDC regulated. The rest of the part values shown are self explanatory. Resistors are all 1/4 watt.

With this setup, If I deliver 5V to the TXDA net (aka output to PC), then the PC will recognize that bit as logic high. If however, I deliver only 3.3V then the PC doesn't want to recognize the bit.

The PC is able to output data to the micro through the RXDA pin just fine in all cases.

In my circuit, I connected pins 4, 1, and 6 of the serial port together and pins 7 and 8 together to make it compatible with all computers and to try to eliminate EMI.

Is there a way I can get this circuit so that it recognizes data at low voltages?

The reason I'm making such a circuit is because I'm simulating an HM-TRP wireless data module (that refuses to work at more than 3.9V) and I want to see and control the data on my computer so that later when I actually use the module instead of the computer, everything will then work.

And for those who ask, the voltage regulator I used to generate 3.3V from 5V is LM1117-3.3

Comment: What's wrong with using a USB-UART bridge?

Comment: As far as I remember RS232 logic 1 is -3 to -12 V and logic 0 is +3 to +12 V. You are out of specification if you're transmitting at 3 V. Use a MAX232 or similar.

Comment: @Transistor My recollection is -3 to -15, +3 to +15, with a required ability to tolerate without damage, -25 and +25. But computers have changed, USB is everywhere, and FTDI chips (and clones) abound. So I'm pretty sure the OP has little to almost no knowledge about real RS-232 specs and uses the term as a replacement for "asynch serial communications with FTDI-like ICs." If the OP really does have a true RS-232 port, I'd be shocked. My guess would be a virtual COM port, instead.

Comment: They do still make motherboards that have serial ports wired to headers on the board, but they need a bracket (sold separately [from someone else, not the mobo manufacturer]) to be externally accessible.

Comment: I'm doing a project that uses wireless communications via UART (which is what the HM-TRP chip runs with). My project doesn't use usb at all. Be shocked jonk, I have a true RS-232 port on my computers.

Comment: @Mike Cool! Then you probably should take the time to call that out, more clearly. The world has changed so much that it is needed, I think. I know you said RS-232. But these days it is too easy to go in several directions with it.

Comment: RS-232 has the same 1.4~1.5v threshold as 74HCTxx logic and TTL.  But if you put 3.3V Tx  with Vcc= >4V the transistor is ON all the time. So use the same Vcc as your UART and 74HCT logic.  Good enough for short haul twisted pairs.

Comment: So I can make the VCC of this circuit to 3.3V and make TX a 3.3V or 0V value and then the PC will then recognize the data through the port? and what about my component values? are they OK? For data, I'm doing 9600bps half-duplex

Comment: Oh  I wanted to add that what I didn't show here in my circuit was VCC being connected to a jumper that allows me to use 3.3V or 5V to power the whole thing. At first I didn't want to power it with 3.3V because I thought maybe it wasn't high enough given my resistor values to power the circuit correctly so then I tried 5V. Now that I got your comment Tony, I'm going to try again after with 3.3V for VCC and see what happens.

Comment: Tony is right. After fiddling around and using 3.3V as VCC, I was able to read data.

Comment: @Mike I should have looked at the circuit, earlier (I didn't.) Do you see how the circuit develops appropriate negative voltage values to use in communicating with the RS-232 device? I'm interested in knowing if you can see that trick. Then I have a question. Is the only problem you are having related to using 3.3 V for TXDA?

Comment: I think it has to do with the diode and capacitor

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 would you like to post your correct answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RS-232 has the same 1.4~1.5v threshold as 74HCTxx logic and TTL. This standard threshold is backwards compatible to all families of TTL but implemented many ways using diodes, 2 Vbe's etc.

But if you put 3.3V Tx with Vcc= >4V the transistor is ON all the time.

So use the same Vcc as your UART and 74HCT logic.

Good enough for short haul and better with twisted pairs Rx/gnd, Tx/gnd. 8 turns/ft